# Check if a string is present in multiple lists

Tags: python, pandas, list, numpy

I am trying to categorize a dataset based on the string that contains the name of the different objects of the dataset.

The dataset is composed of 3 columns, df['Name'], df['Category'] and df['Sub_Category'], the Category and Sub_Category columns are empty.

For each row I would like to check in different lists of words if the name of the object contains at least one word in one of the list. Based on this first check I would like to attribute a value to the category column. If it finds more than 1 word in 2 different lists I would like to attribute 2 values to the object in the category column.

Moreover, I would like to be able to identify which word has been checked in which list in order to attribute a value to the sub_category column.

Until now, I have been able to do it with only one list, but I am not able to identity which word has been checked and the code is very long to run.

Here is my code (where I added an example of names found in my dataset as df['Name']) :

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

df['Name'] = ['vitrine murale vintage','commode ancienne', 'lustre antique', 'solex', 'sculpture médievale', 'jante voiture', 'lit et matelas', 'turbine moteur']

furniture_check = ['canape', 'chaise', 'buffet','table','commode','lit']
vehicle_check = ['solex','voiture','moto','scooter']
art_check = ['tableau','scuplture', 'tapisserie']
    for idx, row in df.iterrows():
        for c in furniture_check:
            if c in row['Name']:
                df.loc[idx, 'Category'] = 'Meubles'
```

Any help would be appreciated

Answer (score 0):

Here is an approach that expands lists, merges them and re-combines them.

```
df = pd.DataFrame({"name":['vitrine murale vintage','commode ancienne', 'lustre antique', 'solex', 'sculpture médievale', 'jante voiture', 'lit et matelas', 'turbine moteur']})
furniture_check = ['canape', 'chaise', 'buffet','table','commode','lit']
vehicle_check = ['solex','voiture','moto','scooter']
art_check = ['tableau','scuplture', 'tapisserie']

# put categories into a dataframe
dfcat = pd.DataFrame([{"category":"furniture","values":furniture_check},
             {"category":"vechile","values":vehicle_check},
             {"category":"art","values":art_check}])

# turn apace delimited "name" column into a list
dfcatlist = (df.assign(name=df["name"].apply(lambda x: x.split(" ")))
              # explode list so it can be used as join.  reset_index() to keep a copy of index of original DF
 .explode("name").reset_index()
              # merge exploded names on both side
 .merge(dfcat.explode("values"), left_on="name", right_on="values")
              # where there are multiple categoryies, make it a list
 .groupby("index", as_index=False).agg({"category":lambda s: list(s)})
              # but original index back...
 .set_index("index")
)

# simple join and have names and list of associated categories
df.join(dfcatlist)
```

|  | name | category |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 0 | vitrine murale vintage | nan |
| 1 | commode ancienne | ['furniture'] |
| 2 | lustre antique | nan |
| 3 | solex | ['vechile'] |
| 4 | sculpture médievale | nan |
| 5 | jante voiture | ['vechile'] |
| 6 | lit et matelas | ['furniture'] |
| 7 | turbine moteur | nan |